# PHP, calculate time since added

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this function that calculates the time elapsed since a row was added into a database:

```
function added_on($time){
    $now = time();
    $time = $now - $time; 

    $blocks = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($blocks as $unit => $size) {
        if ($time < $unit) 
            continue;

        $nrOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $nrOfUnits.' '.$size.(($nrOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}
```

The problem with this is that is not accurate, i.e has an error of about 7 hours behind.
When called on a current time, it returns like: added 7 hours ago.
Function is called as:

```
$posted_on = strtotime($row['created_at']);
echo 'added '.added_on($posted_on).' ago';
```

Where `$row['created_at']` is MySQL Date type

thank you

Comment: So, what's your question? That it's not accurate? Are the time zones the same?

Comment: why has the 7 hours error ?

Comment: Are you sure that `$time` is a timestamp and are they in the same time zone?

Comment: $time is a timestamp. For the time zone, seems to be the same; if I add now a row, the timestamp is as my time on the local machine. I'm testing this on local machine (server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first blush I'm guessing different time zones.  A different way to accomplish the same task  in pure MySql follows:

```
select time_to_sec(timediff(now(), created_at)) as seconds_ago from `table_name`
```

To help you debug more you can check and set the timezone of the mysql server with the following ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html)):

```
-- Check the global and session time_zone settings
select @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;

-- Set the time zone to GMT -5 hours (EST):
set SESSION time_zone = '-5:00';
```